# How to check SQL, Language syntax in String at compile time (Scala)

Tags: scala, macros, thrift, dsl, shapeless

I am writing a translator which converts DSL to multiple programming language (It seems like [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/)).

For example,

```
// an example DSL
LOG_TYPE: COMMERCE

COMMON_FIELD : session_id

KEY: buy
FIELD: item_id, transaction_id 

KEY: add_to_cart
FIELD: item_id

// will be converted to Java
class Commerce {
  private String session_id
  private String key;
  private String item_id;
  private String transaction_id

  // auto-created setter, getter, helper methods 
  ...
}
```

It also should be translated into objective-c and javascript.

To implement it, I have to replace string

```
// 1. create or load code fragments
String variableDeclarationInJava = "private String {$field};";
String variableDeclarationInJavascript = "...";
String variableDeclarationInObjC = "...";

// 2. replace it
variableDeclarationInJava.replace(pattern, fieldName)
...
```

Replacing code fragment in String is not type safe and frustrating since it does not any information even if there are errors.

So, my question is **It is possible to parse String at compile time?** like [Scala sqltyped library](https://github.com/jonifreeman/sqltyped)

If it is possible, I would like to know how can I achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can hardly check SQL syntax at compile time, as it depends on the DB vendor. Can use macro and/or string interpolation to check string syntax.

Comment: In my case, it would be easier than SQL syntax checking since I have to validate **restricted** language syntax (e.g creating function, class, variables..) Could you recommend some useful resource for macro to translate DSL?

Comment: There are various existing open projects doing so (e.g Slick). You can look at sources.

Answer (score 3):

As far, as I understand, it could be. Please take a look at string interpolation. You implement a custom interpolator, (like it was done for quasi quotations or in Slick).

A nice example of the thing you may want to do is [here](https://github.com/limansky/mongoquery)

Comment: Thanks @ppopoff :) I will take a look *string interpolation*